# Jest/React mock scrollBy and .getBoundingClientRect function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs, spy

I have a function handleClick which uses scrollBy on an element which gets its first argument using getBoundingClientRect. I am trying to test this using jest/enzyme.

```
class myClass extends Component  {
    ...
    ...
    handleClick () {
        document.getElementById('first-id').scrollBy(document.getElementById('second-id').getBoundingClientRect().width, 0);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button className="my-button" onClick={this.handleClick()}>scroll</button>
        );
    }
}
```

My test:

```
it('calls scrollBy with correct params', () => {
    const props = {};
    myClassWrapper = mount(<myClass {...props} />);
    const scrollBySpy = jest.fn();
    global.document.getElementById = jest.fn(() => ({ scrollBy: scrollBySpy }));

    myClassWrapper.find('my-button').simulate('click');
    // expect(scrollBySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith()
});
```

I am trying to test that scrollBy is getting called with correct params, but I get the following error when running this test:

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getBoundingClientRect is not a function]
```

Sorry if this has been answered before but I could not see anything which answers my scenario. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`scrollBy` is called on the first result of `getElementById`, and `getBoundingClientRect` is called on the second result of `getElementById` so you'll need to include both functions on the object you are returning in the mock.

Here is a working example to get you started:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    document.getElementById('first-id').scrollBy(document.getElementById('second-id').getBoundingClientRect().width, 0);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button className="my-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>scroll</button>
    );
  }
}

it('calls scrollBy with correct params', () => {
  const props = {};
  const myClassWrapper = mount(<MyClass {...props} />);
  const scrollBySpy = jest.fn();
  const getBoundingClientRectSpy = jest.fn(() => ({ width: 100 }));
  global.document.getElementById = jest.fn(() => ({
    scrollBy: scrollBySpy,
    getBoundingClientRect: getBoundingClientRectSpy  // <= add getBoundingClientRect
  }));

  myClassWrapper.find('.my-button').simulate('click');
  expect(scrollBySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(100, 0);  // Success!
});
```