# Jest Enzyme: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jest-enzyme

Can anyone help please: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null.

```
handleInformationIcon = (setIndex, index) => {
    this.setState({ TooltipCheck: !this.state.TooltipCheck, activeTooltip: setIndex });
    const toolTipElement = document.getElementById(`tooltip_${index}`).getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const pageBottomHeight = window.innerHeight - toolTipElement;
    if ((pageBottomHeight < 200) && !this.state.TooltipCheck) {
      window.scrollBy({
        top: 200,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
}

renderTooltip = (message, index) => (
    <div
      className="tier-tooltip"
      id={`tooltip_${index}`}
    >
      <button
        role="link"
        type="button"
        tabIndex="0"
        aria-expanded={this.state.isTooltipCollapse}
        aria-label={this.props.resources.infoIcon}
        onClick={() => this.handleInformationIcon(`${index}__tier-tooltip`, index)}
        className={`icon icon-information tooltip${index}`}
      />

      {this.state.activeTooltip === `${index}__tier-tooltip` && (
        <div
          className={sn('tier-tooltip-text', this.state.TooltipCheck ? 'isOpen' : '')}
          tabIndex={0}
        >
          <EnhancedRichText
            className="tooltip__body"
            htmlText={message}
          />
          <FocusoutButton
            role="link"
            onClick={this.handleInformationIconHide}
            className="link modal__close"
            aria-label={this.props.resources.infoPopoverClose}
          >
            <span className="icon icon-close" />
          </FocusoutButton>
        </div>
      )}
      {this.state.TooltipCheck && (
        <div
          className="tooltip__backdrop"
          onClick={this.handleInformationIconHide}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  )

render = () => {
   return (
       {this.renderToolTip(message,0)}
   )
}
```

I tried using the test cases specified in this one but still they are failing for this piece of code : [Jest/React mock scrollBy and .getBoundingClientRect function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816714/jest-react-mock-scrollby-and-getboundingclientrect-function).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this.
Reference : https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1590#issuecomment-578350151

```html
 const htmlElment = document.createElement('div');
    htmlElment.setAttribute('id', 'tooltip_0');
    htmlElment.getBoundingClientRect = jest.fn(() => ({
      x: 851.6,
      y: 200.0,
      width: 8.3,
      height: 17,
      top: 967.0,
      right: 860.0,
      bottom: 984.0,
      left: 851.6,
    }));
    const elementMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => htmlElment);
    document.getElementById = elementMock;
```